# How do I build a dataframe by stacking function outputs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function

I want to build a data frame by stacking function outputs.

How do I build a dataframe by stacking function outputs?

This is my code.
plz help me..

```
for x in range(583,625):
 try :
    # input var
    seq, title, end_period, upload_count, goal_count, total_reward, per_price, explain = Crawling(x)
    
    # DataFrame
    CloudPick = {'seq': seq, 'title': title, 'end_period':end_period, 'upload_count':upload_count, 'goal_count':goal_count, 'total_reward':total_reward, 'per_price':per_price, 'explain':explain }
    CloudPick_df = pd.DataFrame(CloudPick, index=[0])
    CloudPick_df.set_index('seq', inplace=True)
    print(CloudPick_df)

 except:
    print(x, 'fail')
```

Comment: create a function which returns a dataframe, then use `pandas.concat` with a list comprehension https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html.  Eg `pd.concat([myfunc(x) for x in range(583,625)]`

Comment: @Riley Wow... Thank you for Answer!!!! This is working for me!!! You are the best developer!!!